# Remove characters before and after particular subtring in a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am new to Python.May be this can be done with regex.I want to search for a particular substring in a string and remove characters before and after that in the string.

Example 1

```
Input:"This is the consignment no 1234578TP43789"
Output:"This is the consignment no TP"
```

Example 2

```
Input:"Consignment no 1234578TP43789 is on its way on vehicle no 3456MP567890"
Output:"Consignment no TP is on its way on vehicle no MP"
```

I have list of the these acronyms(`MP`,`TP`) to be searched in the string.

Comment: take a look at the substitute function of the regex module, [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: anything before and after TP. It can contains numbers and characters both.This thing 1234578TP43789 should be replaced by TP in output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
>>> string="This is the consignment no 1234578TP43789"
>>> re.sub(r'\d+(TP|MP)\d+', r'\1', string)
'This is the consignment no TP'

>>> string="Consignment no 1234578TP43789 is on its way on vehicle no 3456MP567890"
>>> re.sub(r'\d+(TP|MP)\d+', r'\1', string)
'Consignment no TP is on its way on vehicle no MP'
```

**What it does?**

- `\d+` Matches one or more digits.
- `(TP|MP)` Matches `TP` or `MP`. Captures it in `\1`. We used this captured string to replace the entire matched string.

---

If any character can appear before and after TP/MP we can use `\S` to match anything other than a space. For example,

```
>>> string="Consignment no 1234578TP43789 is on its way on vehicle no 3456MP567890"
>>> re.sub(r'\S+(TP|MP)\S+', r'\1', string)
'Consignment no TP is on its way on vehicle no MP'
```

**Edit**

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), you can iterate through the list and replace all strings as,

```
>>> list_1=["TP","MP","DCT"]
>>> list_2=["This is the consignment no 1234578TP43789","Consignment no 1234578TP43789 is on its way on vehicle no 3456MP567890"]
>>> [ re.sub(r'\d+(' +  '|'.join(list_1) + ')\d+', r'\1', string) for string in list_2 ]
['This is the consignment no TP', 'Consignment no TP is on its way on vehicle no MP']
```

Comment: @nu11p01n73RThanks a lot

One more thing

list_1=["TP","MP","DCT"] 
list_2=["This is the consignment no 1234578TP43789","Consignment no 1234578TP43789 is on its way on vehicle no 3456MP567890"] 

Now I have to take TP,MP from list_1 search it in strings of list_2 and replace them.How to do that?

Comment: @SalmanBaqri You can generate the regex by using `join` as `'|'.join(["TP","MP","DCT"])` and use it to iterate the `list_2` to generate the required output. You can also use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Could please explain it a bit more?

Comment: I'd add a word boundary and turn `\d+` into `\w+` : https://regex101.com/r/bCTP9R/1 - nevertheless +1

Comment: @nu11p01n73R can you share resources from where I can learn more about Regular expressions.

Comment: @SalmanBaqri http://www.regular-expressions.info/ can give a basic idea about regular expressions. You can play around with regular expressions at https://regex101.com/

Comment: @nu11p01n73R If want the  strings (not replace)from list_2 containing elements of list_1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strip` which strips characters from before and after a string.

```
strg="Consignment no 1234578TP43789 is on its way on vehicle no 3456MP567890"
strg=' '.join([word.strip('0123456789') for word in strg.split()])
print(strg) # Consignment no TP is on its way on vehicle no MP
```

To just strip if a reserved word is contained put it inside a loop

```
strg="Consignment no 1234578TP43789 is on its way on vehicle no 3456MP567890 200DG"
reserved=['MP','TP']
for res in reserved:
    strg=' '.join([word.strip('0123456789') if (res in word) else word for word in strg.split()])
print(strg) # Consignment no TP is on its way on vehicle no MP 200DG
```